# How to upgrade SonarQube from 5.1 to 6.2

Tags: upgrade, sonarqube5.1

What is the exact path to a migration from sonarqube 5.1 to 6.2

Can i upgrade from 5.1 to 5.6.3 to 6.2?

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade using the last fix of 5.6

```
5.1 -> 5.6.6 -> 6.2
```

but the db upgrade should work also with the migration path you suggested.

Anyway, because 6.3.1 fixes some issues of 6.2, I would upgrade

```
5.1 -> 5.6.6 -> 6.3.1
```

Comment: I done 5.1 -> 5.6.3 -> 6.2 but now all my bulk permission are gone now.

Comment: What i have to do to fix my permission?  Did 5.1 -> 5.6.3 -> 6.2 -> 6.3.1 wold fix my permission?

Comment: If I well understood what you mean, try "Projects > Management" then "Bulk Apply Permission Template" to apply a template to all selected projects. See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization for more details.

Comment: Hi, I know that how to apply the bulk permission to a project.

Comment: What i trying to know is how my bulk permission to my project get loss and now all my project have  the default bulk permission. So how can i lose all my bulk permission that i have before the upgrade. And how can i get it back ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer you. May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063174/all-quality-profiles-have-no-rules-when-sonarqube-is-upgraded-to-5-4